# Predicate for Many-To-Many

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data

Trying to wrap my head around predicates and core data. I have a model that looks like this.

House <-->> Room (House has many rooms) 
Room <<-->> Fixtures (rooms have many fixtures and many fixtures can belong to rooms)
Fixtures <-->> Fixture_Types (fixtures have many types)

What should my predicate look like if I have the "House" and I need to get all unique Fixture_types where "room" == "kitchen" (or whatever).

Thanks!

Comment: How can a fixture belong to two rooms at once?

Comment: @MarkAdams - Think about it as fixtures being reused for multiple rooms. It's standard normalization.  Think about a database, for example, where you have an Employee table and a Position table.  Employee can have many positions, and a position (Accounting for example) can be held by many employees.  Same logic applies to _tweeznasty_'s Room-to-Fixtures relationship.

Comment: I understand normalization, but what I don't understand is how a singular instance of `Fixture` can belong to two rooms at once. Following your employee analogy, the many-to-many relationship should be between `Room` and `Fixture_Types` because an accounting position isn't an actual position, occupied by a person, it's a type that can apply to more than one person.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I was merely using Rooms, Fixtures, and Fixture_types as an example. Not actual. So if you can consider the question as a hypothetical. Say my model is Checklist, Template, Template Items, Categories. Where Checklist <-->> Templates, Templates <<-->> Items, Items <-->> Categories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured it out. Here is what I did.

Get the top level object House and its child room - kitchen.

```
Room *room = [house.rooms objectAtIndex:someIndex];
```

I have a display order, so set:

```
NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"displayOrder" ascending:YES];
```

I have a helper function to get objects with a defined predicate, so:

```
+(NSArray *)objectsForEntityNamed:(NSString *)name withPredicate:(NSPredicate *)predicate inContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context{
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:name inManagedObjectContext:context];

    NSFetchRequest *req = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [req setEntity:entity];
    [req setPredicate:predicate];
    NSError *error = nil;

    NSArray *array = [context executeFetchRequest:req error:&error];

    if (array == nil){
        NSException *exception = [NSException exceptionWithName:CoreDataExeption reason:[error localizedDescription] userInfo:nil];

        [exception raise];

    }
    return array;

}
```

And now for the good stuff, where fixture_types in the predicate is the inverse relationship of Fixture_Types to Fixtures. Of course, you can do a distinct but since my db is normalized I should only get unique results anyway:

```
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY fixture_types IN %@", room.fixtures];

NSArray *fixture_types = [[CDUtilities objectsForEntityNamed:@"Fixture_Types" withPredicate:pred inContext:[house managedObjectContext]] sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:descriptor, nil]];
```

Hope this helps someone, let me know if there is a better way to do this or if you have question on how I did it.